# How can I check if a file is created with a background process in PHP?

Tags: php, background-process

I'm waiting for a background process to finish in a installation configuration script written in PHP:

```
$process = new BackgroundProcess("exec openssl genrsa -out " . $privateKeyPath . " 2048");

$process->run();
```

before running the next command which creates the public key:

```
$process = new BackgroundProcess("exec openssl rsa -in " . $privateKeyPath . " -pubout -out " . $publicKeyPath);

$process->run();
```

I'm checking if the file exists in a while loop like this:

```
while(!file_exists($privateKeyPath)) {
    sleep(0.01);
}
```

before running the second background process.

The `BackgroundProcess` instances are created from the [Cocur Background-Process repository](https://github.com/cocur/background-process/blob/master/src/BackgroundProcess.php)

How can I check if the first process is finished and the file is accessible to initiate the second `BackgroundProcess`?

Comment: possibly with exec() or shell_exec() , (p)grep for the processes?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the two commands like that :

```
$process = new BackgroundProcess("exec openssl genrsa -out " . $privateKeyPath . " 2048 && exec openssl rsa -in " . $privateKeyPath . " -pubout -out " . $publicKeyPath);
```

Since linux will exec the first command and wait until it's done to execute the second one.

Maybe not the best idea but it works